# How do I get the request IP address on a SSL request

Tags: c#, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a service that is running in Amazon Ec2. The service exposes both a http endpoint and a https endpoint. I am doing some geo lookup on the user IP address when I log the data. Everything works just fine on requests coming into the http endpoint. I have to grab the X-Forwarded-For header so that I do not take the Amazon Load Balancer UP Address and I am always able to get what I need. However on requests that come in on the https endpoint all of the IP addresses are the same.

In order to pull the IP address I am using the following C# code:

```
    public static string FetchClientIp(HttpRequest req)
    {
        var value = req.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? req.UserHostAddress : value;
    }
```

I can't find anything else that I need to do that is specific to https requests so I'm hoping someone here has run into this before. I'm going to spin up a test on this to try to better isolate the problem.

Thanks

Comment: It's obviously the Amazon traffic manager which is the issue, and it's pretty esoteric so I don't know how much luck you'll have here. Suggest you consult vendor forums or support.

Comment: Crazy suggestion: you know for sure the IP of the endpoint that is connecting with you isn't the client IP address?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you have your ELB set up.

If you're terminating SSL on the ELB ([new feature as of October 2010](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/10/14/amazon-elb-adds-support-for-https/)), then the client IP address will be in "X-Forwarded-For".

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]
```

It sounds like you're terminating SSL on your web servers, then ELB can't decrypt the traffic and add the "X-Forwarded-For" header to the HTTP request.  So the client IP address in the header "REMOTE_ADDR" (which is the header returned by HttpRequest.UserHostAddress) is the IP of the last hop -- in this case the internal IP address of the ELB.

Keep in mind, "X-Forwared-For" may contain multiple IP addresses as described at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?SvcIntro.html#X-Forwarded-For.  In that case, you're probably most interested in the first address listed.